# What is the proper way to push a variable into a "person or group" field with a workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I want to capture a person field as a variable and then use that variable to update another person field. Both are limited to one person, if that makes it any easier.

Answer (score 0):

Save the peoplePicker field as the value: 'userName()', either directly into another peoplePicker field, or into a text field, and then cast that back into a people picker field.

It displays as "First Last" but its not actually saving as that.

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work properly when I try to match it to the same people field in another list.

Comment: Does the user you are trying to add have access to the other list?

Comment: Yes, all permissions are inherited from the same site collection permission groups.

Comment: Try to find out the value being stored into the variable fromt he peoplepicker, you can do this by logging the variable into the history right after it is assigned.  That may give you hints as to why its failing.